# Link to custom google My Maps with hash to control layers

Tags: html, google-maps, url

I have a custom map that I made with https://www.google.com/mymaps and I was wondering if it's possible to link to the map with some kind of URL hash that would determine which map layers to show, or at least some way to link to it and have it focused on a certain location marker?

Will I have to embed the map somewhere to accomplish this via javascript or is there a simpler built-in way? I found some documentation on it but it's so sparse...

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start and try using the embed API.